# Timeout for AuraEnabled method in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I was going through javascript Remoting and lightning auraEnabled methods.

Then I came acrosss the question.
How do we configure timeouts for Aura enabled methods?

**`Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000; // Sets timeout in JS for Remoting call.`**

Do we have something for Aura? and what is the default timeout for aura enabled Method.

Comment: Hi! Did you find the answer?